# Drop, not overwrite, on unique id field

Tags: solr

When using a unique id field, Solr will overwrite old documents with newly indexed documents. Is there any way to prevent this, so that the *old* documents are stored but the new are dropped?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how your application is set up, but it should be aware of whether a document is new or old. So simply don't push the old docs to Solr.

Comment: Thanks, mbonaci. The application putting the documents in Solr is not aware if they already exist or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Solr will delete the existing record and insert a new one by default

You can check for [Deduplication](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Deduplication) and [UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_for_.22add.22) which may serve the purpose.

You can write your own update request handler that detected extend UpdateRequestProcessorFactory/UpdateRequestProcessor.

Else, you can check if the Id exists and then not insert the new record. Overhead on the Client side.

Comment: Thank you, the `overwrite` attribute might be just what I am looking for!